# PhoneGap location issues

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap 1.0 for iOS right now to do some coding with google maps. The system is also running on jQuery Mobile which I think is half the issue.

When trying to pull up the users location I get the following error in the console: Ignoring gap command with incorrect sessionKey; expecting: 615717337 received: (null)

I'm assuming that since the map page is an 'external' page the original phonegap call made on the home screen of the app isn't passing a session along to the other pages. Is there a way to retrieve this sessionKey?

Comment: After doing some more testing the new page still has access to the PhoneGap.sessionKey variable. It looks like it's something inside the iframe created by google maps that is causing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the errors I was experiencing are normal and do not have effect on the geo location. There is currently a bug with the iOS Simulator and PhoneGap that causes geo location services to timeout on the simulator, but everything works as expected on an actual device.